# does blueprintjs have stepper functionality?

Tags: blueprintjs

I am looking the for a similar functionality in blueprintjs, do we have?

Something like below

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/stepper

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one right now, but there's a discussion tracking the feature request here: https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/260